# Consuming Web Service using 2 Way SSL using Orbeon client code

Tags: orbeon, xforms

We are trying to consume web service from orbeon client code. Everything works fine with one way SSL however we now wish to call the web service using 2 way SSL. We are able to call the web service using 2 way SSL successfully using the Apache CXF framework using Java code.

I followed the steps outlined in the [Orbeon Wiki](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/how-to/use-ssl-https).

Changes made in `properties-local.xml`

```xml
<property as="xs:anyURI"
      name="oxf.http.ssl.keystore.uri"
      value="/apps/property/ClientStore.jks"/>
<property as="xs:string"
      name="oxf.http.ssl.keystore.password"
      value="password"/>
<property as="xs:anyURI"
      name="oxf.url-rewriting.service.base-uri"
      value="http://localhost:8085/Orbeon"/>
<property as="xs:anyURI"
      name="oxf.fr.persistence.exist.uri"
      value="http://localhost:8085/fr/service/exist"/>
<property as="xs:anyURI"
      name="oxf.fr.persistence.exist.exist-uri"
      value="http://localhost:8085/exist/rest/db/orbeon/fr"/>
```

After implementing the changes outlined above we are getting the exception below:

```
ERROR XFormsServer  - xforms-submit-error - setting throwable {throwable:
    "javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:128)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:390)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:488)
    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SchemeSocketFactoryAdaptor.connectSocket(SchemeSocketFactoryAdaptor.java:62)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:148
```

Java start up options are:

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=password
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/apps/property/DMClientStore.jks 
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=password
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/apps/property/trustkeystore.jks
```

Questions:

1. Are these properties sufficient for enabling 2 way SSL?
2. For Apache CXF we need to provide two keystores, one with the client certificate and a truststore. Where do we configure both of these keystores for Orbeon?